# what is alternative of memcached_dump in libcouchbase?

Tags: couchbase, libmemcached

1. as I observe did not found any alternative of memcached_dump in libcouchbase api.
2. I have seen tap function in 1.8 version but as i observe it is not their in 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

1. As far as i know `stats cachedump` command isn't supported by couchbase, therefore you cannot dump all the keys. Probably 'Couchbase Views' feature will help you get this list
2. Yes, libcouchbase doesn't support TAP protocol right now